# How to report intellij IDE Fatal Errors?

Tags: intellij-idea

I encountered an error when using intellij, and it suggests to submit a bug report in the notification; I clicked it and a window like below jumped out. I wrote some words in the text area but the "Peport to JetBrains" button is still invalid.

It seems that there is no other area to write: "Error message" and "Details" tab  area are both non-writable.

So how can I report "IDE Fatal Errors" within intellij?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not a programming question.

Comment: it's not. but where do you suggest to ask this question?

Comment: @vikingsteve: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic says that questions about software tools commonly used by programmers are on-topic. IntelliJ IDEA is certainly one such tool

Comment: disagree that stackoverflow should be used for bug reports. such reports, as you describe as "noisy", can go directly to the developer.

Comment: @vikingsteve no it's not bug report. i was asking *how to* report and Mr. yole answered that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the "Report to JetBrains" button is disabled is that the exception happened in a third-party plugin. Reporting third-party plugin issues to JetBrains is not useful, because we can't do anything to resolve these issues. Therefore, to minimize noise in our issue tracking system, reporting such exceptions is disabled.

Comment: okay, i see. i think the plugin may be protobuf configuration. where can i report to for this plugin when next time i found similar report?

Comment: If the developer of the plugin provided contact information, you can find it on plugins.jetbrains.com and in the Plugins settings pane in IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

The EXA is our Exception Analyzer subsystem, which is not visible to the outside user currently.

You can try adding idea.fatal.error.notification=disabled in Help | Edit Custom Properties and restart IDE to disable the reporting though it doesn't disable the error message that occurred from the plugin